# Java: не могу получить значение поля супер класса в дочернем

Tags: java

Изучаю Java и столкнулся с проблемой получения значения поля родителя в дочернем классе. Подскажите куда копать для решения вопроса.

Как я понимаю написанный мной код: В методе main класса Main создается объект 'B'.Конструктор 'B' присваивает значение 10 полю 'int number' класса 'B'.Класс 'C' является наследником класса 'B' и должен иметь доступ ко всем его полям и методам. Но когда в классе 'C' я пытаюсь получить значение поля 'number' класса 'B' и вывести его на экран с помощью метода 'print', то получаю значение по умолчанию-0. Что мне нужно сделать, что бы получить значение поля 'number' из класса 'B' в классе 'C'?
Если в 'B' поле сделать 'static int number' и обращаться к нему в 'C'-B.number, то все работает правильно. а как сделать это без static ?
Код следующий:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B(10);
        new C().print();
    }
}
```

```
public class B {
    int number;
    
B(int number){
    this.number=number;
}
B(){};
}
```

```
public class C extends B{

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Result = "+number);
    }
}
```

Ожидается значение: 10
Получаю значение по умолчанию:0

Пробовал разные варианты с this, super, создавал новый объект 'B' в классе 'С'.Не выходит каменный цветок).

Comment: Вас не смущает, что в `new B(10)` Вы указываете 10, а у `new C()` - нет? Уже отсюда должен был возникнуть вопрос: как этот `C` узнает, чего Вы от него хотите?

Comment: И сразу ответ на следующий вопрос, который должен у Вас возникнуть: надо у класса `C` создать конструктор с `int` параметром и вызывать в нём конструктор родителя с этим же параметром в роли аргумента.

Comment: public class C extends B{
C(int number){
    super(number);
}} так получается? Тогда при создании объекта 'С' в Main классе требует ввести параметр

Comment: Если вам нужно без ввода параметра, то напишите `super(10);`

Comment: `new C()` - создает новый объект, у которого член класса `number` не присваивается и имеет значение по умолчанию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ты создал 2 разных объекта `B b = new B(10);` B с параметром 10
и `new C()` с дефолтными параметрами.

когда ты создаёшь объект класса С `new C()`
дефолтный конструктор подкласса вызывает дефолтный конструктор суперкласса  `B(){}`

поля класса по умолчанию инициализируются дефолтными значениями, поэтому выводится `0`

объект класса `С` ничего не знает про состояние класса `B`, `C` просто создан по образу и подобию `В`

чтобы создать `С` с нужными параметрами, надо в конструкторе подкласса вызвать конструктор суперкласса через ключевое слово `super`

```
 public C(int number) {
        //с заданным параметром
        super(number); 
    }

    public C() {
        // устанавливаем параметр по умолчанию
        super(10);
    }
```